# In Zend, how do I use my application.ini database settings?

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to authenticate right now, and I need a db adapter for MySQL. Currently, I am going to use this:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

However, it doesn't make sense to hardcode it into the controller when I have my `resources.db.*` set in my  application.ini. My question is, how can I have my controller grab the information in the application.ini for my db adapter? Could you please link the relevant documentation page that I am desperately looking for too?

Answer (score 2):

To access your application resources, you would need to access to the bootstrap object of your Zend_Application, The one you created in your index.php file. You could store either of them somewhere accessible from everywhere, say a Zend_Registry.
Suppose this is your public/index.php file:

```
    // suppose you have defined the APPLICATION_PATH constant to the application
    // directory of your project. and the APPLICATION_ENV defines your environment
    // like production, development or testing.
    // create a config for your application configurations, defining your resources
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(
                APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
                APPLICATION_ENV
            );
    // this is the application object
    $application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, $config);

    // now resources are bootstrapping
    $application->bootstrap();
    $bootstrap = $application->getBootstrap();

    // store them somewhere in registry, so you could access them from everywhere
    // like controllers, models, etc.
    Zend_Registry::set('application', $application);
```

Now in your controller (or any other code, like models, view, etc.), you could access this application object using:

```
   $application = Zend_Registry::get('application'):
   /*@var $application Zend_Application*/
   $bootstrap = $application->getBootstrap();
   // now you could access any resources from the $bootstrap object

   $db = $bootstrap->getResource('db');
   $log = $bootstrap->getResource('log);
   // now $db is a Zend_Db object bootstrapped from your application config
```

This is a general way of accessing application bootstrap. However in your controllers there is another way to access the bootstrap object (and so the resources), and that is using the '''getInvokeArg('bootstrap')''' of the controller object. So in your controller you could do:

```
  $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
  $db = $bootstrap->getResource('db');
  // now $db is a Zend_Db object bootstrapped from your application config
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Bootstrap.php file in the run function add:

```
public function run() {
  //Any other code you already had in the run function could go here
  //Add this line to your function
  Zend_Registry::set('options', $this->getOptions());
}
```

Then in your controller you can access the database connection settings by doing something like:

```
$options = Zend_Registry::get('options')
$host = $options['resources']['db']['params']['host'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Bootstrap.php (`/application/Bootstrap.php`) file, create a function called `_initDb()` like so:

```
protected function _initDb()
{
    $db = $this->getPluginResource('db');
    // ...
}
```